# Why do Slack thread cards flow upwards instead of downwards?

Tags: position, chat

Today someone replied to a [thread](https://slackhq.com/threaded-messaging-comes-to-slack-417ffba054bd) in Slack, but I was not focused on that particular channel, so Slack attracted my attention to the "All Threads" page on the sidebar.

To my surprise, when I opened that page, the thread my colleague had replied to appeared not at the bottom of the window, but at the top.

I was surprised because with all other Slack conversations (and most chat apps I use) all the recent action happens at the bottom.

(Additionally it looks like the reply text box might change position a little, depending on the length of the thread.)

So, why did they do it this way, instead of arranging the thread cards from top to bottom?

[image]

Comment: this seems related: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/37818/what-is-better-than-top-posting-and-bottom-posting

Answer (score 2):

Because it is not a chat, it is a feed with the messages. And in feeds, because of the actuality, the newest messages are at the top.

Comment: The main window shows newest things at the bottom whereas the threads panel shows newest at the top.  Whatever "the actuality"(?) is, it's horribly inconsistent and seems designed to confuse.