# Where to place the first message in a chat?

Tags: messages, chat

Imagine a simple messenger app. Where to place the first message(s) in a chat? See examples below.

[image: A or B in a messenger]

E.g. Slack, Facebook's Messenger does it the A way. Snapchat, WhatsApp does it the B way.

I'd argue the B way is more correct due to F reading pattern, however, can someone shed me some light on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be related to [bottom/top posting](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/37818/what-is-better-than-top-posting-and-bottom-posting). If users are conditioned to look above the text input for the latest response, aligning to the bottom (example A) would make it more consistent.

If 95% of a user's chats have enough messages in them to scroll, then it might be weird to start a new chat and see the first few messages aligned to the top (example B).

I don't think it's a big deal either way, there doesn't seem to be any standardization on this yet.

Comment: +1 For "not a big deal". Both methods are usable.

Answer (score 2):

[F-shaped reading pattern](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/f-shaped-pattern-reading-web-content-discovered/) is observed in text scanning applied when reading regular web-content like pages or articles.

For chat and messaging applications the timeline of posts may follow a different flow (see top- snd bottom-posting).

So the scan for new posts pattern applied by users might also expect the newly typed message to directly bubble up like a balloon above the text input field. This would also mean a shorter distance for the eyes. Reading starts at the input field (bottom) and after submission the focus moves slightly atop to the last recently posted message.